# which monitoring and collection indicators are recommended to be opened in MySQL performance schema?

Tags: mysql

In addition to the indicators that are automatically opened by default, which monitoring and collection indicators are recommended to be opened in MySQL performance schema?

Comment: Since this question is about performance monitoring of a database, not about programming, it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO provides help with questions like this.

Comment: I like the slowlog for discovering performance bottlenecks.